# Syncing SQL and Active Directory. C# App NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, notimplementedexception

I have an exception in the EventLog for my application like this:

```
Application: Synchronizator_AD.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NotImplementedException Stack:    at
Synchronizator_AD.Application.Database(Synchronizator_AD.Databases,
System.String, System.String, System.String)    at
Synchronizator_AD.Application.Start(System.String)    at
Synchronizator_AD.Synchronizator_AD.TimerTick(System.Object)    at
System.Threading._TimerCallback.TimerCallback_Context(System.Object)  at
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback(System.Object)
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?
I can share with my code If you can help me( VS2010 )

I am writing an application that would create user account in Active Directory with the name from SQL table record. This application is a windows service. This project has few files of code.

Comment: I am writing an application that would create user account in Active Directory with the name from SQL table record. This application is a windows service. Here is the code:

Comment: If you have information to add, please edit the question and add it there - not in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you wrote the `Synchronizator_AD` application. A `System.NotImplementedException` usually indicates that you used some kind of auto-code generation (maybe from some template in Visual Studio) which generated the application frame code for you. These tools quite often insert `throw new System.NotImplementedException()` calls into generated methods because you are the one who has to implement these methods.

So what you are doing wrong is basically: You have not implemented some method which you need to. Find all instances of `throw new System.NotImplementedException()` and implement those methods.

Comment: How do I find all instances of throw new System.NotImplementerException() ?

Comment: @TomaszRebus In Visual Studio: Hit Ctrl-F and in the popup window which opens type in `NotImplementedException` in the search field and below that there is a drop down box where you can select the search scope - select "Entire Solution"

Comment: Select Quick Find from the Edit menu, enter `NotImplementedException` in the `Find what` box, select `Entire Solution` from the `Look in` dropdown and press the `Find Next` button. Once you have found one, you can right-click on it and select `Find All References`. This will show you everywhere it is used.

Comment: Also, welcome to Stackoverflow. Keep in mind that if an answer to your question solves or helps you solve your question, you should click on the checkmark next to that answer. And, in the future, when you have enough reputation, you should also click the up arrow above the number next to the answer.